# gwt css uibinder sharing resource

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I've defined a ClientBundle, a Style interface and hooked it up with my css file via the @source annotation.

I have two questions:

1. when I use `<ui:with>` in my uibinder file I get the following exception: `Deferred binding result type MyStyle should not be abstract.`  Can someone explain what's going on?  And how I can include the style correctly in my uibinder file?
2. I'd like to share the resource across many uibinder without paying the penalty of initializing the style every time.  Gwt's anemic dev guide, suggests using the `UiField(provided=true)` or using a `@uiFactory`.  Although I've successfully used @uiFactory in order to use my own custom widgets.  I have no idea how to use a @uiFactory to inject a style into the uiBinder.

For example:

```
//in pojo
@UiFactory
public MyStyle getMyStyle() {
    return myStyle;
}

//in uibinder
<g:Label addStyleNames="{myStyle.defaultLable}"/>
```

how can i get this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following construction in the uibinder file:

```
<ui:with field='res' type="com.example.client.resources.MyResource" />
```

Where `MyResource` is an interface containing the css resource:

```
public interface MyResource extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("mycss.css")
  MyCssResource css();
}
```

and `MyCssResource` is:

```
public interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
    String someStyle();
}
```

In uibinder file this is used as follows:

```
<g:TextBox addStyleNames="{res.css.someStyle}" />
```

Comment: Thank you...your explanation helped me get passed my first problem.  Do you happend to know how I can share the same resource across multiple uibinder files.  I'd like to create my bundle once.  Thanks again!

Comment: Don't worry to much about it, because the GWT compiler will inline it, so the resource initialization you have in each uibinder isn't an issue in the generated JavaScript. In your code you can use a static instance shared over all classes. Make sure you call `ensureInjected` in your startup code, so the resource in the uibinder files are actually injected.

Comment: I see, thank you for this...you know in the gwt 'documentation':  (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Share_resource_instances).  They describe how to get around the ui:with clause by using the @uiFactory annotation.  Have you been able to get that working?